# Quasi-linear PDE - solution process looks correct, yet solution isn't

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

This is a quasi-linear PDE $$u_t+uu_x=-ku^2$$
where $k>0$, $t>0$, $u(x,0)=1$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

And here's how I'm solving it:

Take parametrization of the surface $u(x,t)$ as $x=x(s), t=t(s), u=u(s)$. Now, $t_s=1, x_s=u, u_s = -ku^2$, and the initial conditions are as follows: $t_{s=0}=0$, $x_{s=0}=\tau$, $u_{s=0}=1$. From these ODE IVPs we get the following results: $t=s$, $u=\frac{1}{kt+1}$.

But Maple shows a completely different solution, which I don't even know how to read. I'd appreciate some hints on what I'm not doing right.

Comment: Your result $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{kt+1}$ is OK. Bringing it back into the PDE shows that it fits. Also it satisfies the condition $u(x,0)=1$. Since you don't show what exactly you did with Maple and what Maple's answer you got, it is impossible to answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_t+uu_x=-ku^2$$
An alternative approach (but equivalent) without parametrisation :

The characteristic equations are :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{-ku^2}$$
A first characteristic curve comes from $\frac{dt}{1}+\frac{du}{ku^2}=0\quad\to\quad t-\frac{1}{ku}=c_1$

A second characteristic curve comes from $\frac{dx}{u}+\frac{du}{ku^2}=0\quad\to\quad ue^{kx}=c_2$

The general solution of the PDE expressed on an implicit form :
$$\Phi\left(c_1\:,\:c_2\right)=\Phi\left(t-\frac{1}{ku}\:,\:ue^{kx}\right)=0$$
any differentiable function $\Phi$ of two variables.

Solving the implicit equation for the first variable leads to :
$$t-\frac{1}{ku}=F(ue^{kx})$$
any differentiable function $F$.

With condition $u(x,0)=1 \quad\to\quad 0-\frac{1}{k}=F(e^{kx})$

which shows that $F$ is constant any value of the variable and is equal to $-\frac{1}{k}$

Hense $t-\frac{1}{ku}=F=-\frac{1}{k} \quad\to\quad \frac{1}{u}=kt+1$
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{kt+1}$$